# Next and previous link in custom post type in the same taxonomy term

Tags: next-post-link

I have a custom post type `name->('portfolio')`, with a taxonomy name `'portfolio_category'`.

What I want is to add next and previous links on its single page file which is single-portfolio.php. When I click either of the links, it should redirect to the next or previous post in the same post type and in the same taxonomy term.

I used `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` but it seems that it only works in single post but not in single custom post type..

Any suggestions will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I can recommend the following plugin, [next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress](http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress) I'm using it with 3.5.x without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

[previous_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) and [next_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) work perfectly with custom post types. You need to paste this code in your single-customposttype.php (which in your case is single-portfolio.php):

```
<div class="previous-post-link">
                <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<< Previous Post', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'the-custom-taxonomy-associated-with-your-custom-post-type'); ?>                    
            </div>

            <div class="next-post-link">
                <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post >>', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'the-custom-taxonomy-associated-with-your-custom-post-type'); ?>                    
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$taxonomy` parameter for both [`next_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) and [`previous_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) was introduced in Wordpress version 3.8.

When the `$in_same_term` parameter is set to true, you need to set the `$taxonomy` parameter to the desired taxonomy. By default, it is set to `category`. Remember, `post_format` is also a taxonomy

Example:

```
next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE, ' ', 'post_format' );
```

Just a note, do not use [`next_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post) and [`previous_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post). It has already being depreciated as from Wordpress version 2.0.0. See [wp-includes/deprecated.php#L121](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/deprecated.php#L121) and [wp-includes/deprecated.php#L158](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/deprecated.php#L158)

**EDIT**

The single post links will automatically page between posts within the same post type as the current post's post type is used to retrieve the adjacent posts. Check the source code, [`get_adjacent_post()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1460) which is used by the next and previous post links. Pay particular attention to line 1550 ( currently for version 4.1 )

```
1550    $where = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_where", $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE p.post_date $op %s AND p.post_type = %s AND p.post_status = 'publish' $where", $current_post_date, $post->post_type ), $in_same_term, $excluded_terms );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your single-cpt.php file.

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous in CPT', TRUE) ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next in CPT', TRUE) ?>
```

Where cpt is the name of your custom post type.

Comment: `previous_post` and `next_post` has been depreciated since v2.0.0 which was released in 2005

Answer (score -1):

Try this is with thumbnail:

```
<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(); if($prevPost) { ?>
    <li class="previous">
    <?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(80,80) ); ?>
        <?php previous_post_link('%link', $prevthumbnail . '<strong>Prev</strong> <span>%title</span>', TRUE); ?>
    </li>
<?php } $nextPost = get_next_post(); if($nextPost) { ?>
    <li class="next">
    <?php $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(80,80) ); ?>
        <?php next_post_link('%link', $nextthumbnail . '<strong>Next</strong> <span>%title</span>', TRUE); ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Code-only answer is worst. Try to add some direction or description by [editing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/143013/edit) it. :)

Comment: I think you missed the question here. The OP did not ask for links with thumnails. Also, code only answers is not considered as a good answer

Comment: Thanks, that help me a lot. With a few css adjustments I ended up with a pretty nice navigation. I've set the previous/next nav to have a fixed position, while setting position absolute for each one so they could be displayed on left/right side of the screen.